# How to rename column names from a list in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, rename

I have about 20000 columns and i want to rename them based on "list of keywords"
For example if i have df like this:

**df**

```
Column: This is a Cat          Column: Dog is faithful          Column: I have pigeon.
A                                      c                                    e  
b                                      d                                    f
```

and i have list like:

```
pets_name = ['cat', 'Dog', 'Pigeon', 'Parrot']
```

I would like to have **desired output** where cat appear then column name should be cat. for dog dog etc like this:

```
   Cat                                    Dog                                pigeon
    A                                      c                                    e  
    b                                      d                                    f
```

Is there any way possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) method with `df.columns` and joined all values of lists with `|` for regex `or`:

```
pets_name = ['Cat', 'Dog', 'pigeon', 'Parrot']
df.columns = df.columns.str.extract('('+ '|'.join(pets_name) + ')', expand=False)

print (df)
  Cat Dog pigeon
0   A   c      e
1   b   d      f
```

Comment: Thanks. Its what i wanted. Can you give me any link for documentation where i can learn about this ? The code is working poperly but i am not sure about this "round_brackets" etc.